# Number stored as text when converted CSV to Xlsx

Tags: python-2.7

I wrote a code to convert/copy CSV file into Xlsx file. It copied the data successfully but all the data stored as text.
Now it is showing an exclamation mark on each data and when it is showing "Number stored as text" .
Can anyone pls help me how to get the data in number because i want to do manipulation on data.
here is the code:

```
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
with open(plotDir + '\\' + file, 'r') as f:
     for row in csv.reader(f):
         ws.append(row)
     wb.save(plotDir + '\\' + file[:-4] + '.xlsx')
```

Comment: You can use set_value_explicit with TYPE_NUMERIC. On a side note, you can do the save file only once after your loop.

Comment: can you pls give an example for set_value_explicit with TYPE_NUMERIC?

Answer (score 0):

You can use set_value_explicit :

```
 with open(plotDir + '\\' + plotFile, 'r') as f:
   for x, row in enumerate( csv.reader(f), start=1):
      for y, val in enumerate(row, start=1):
          ws.cell(row=x,column=y).set_explicit_value(value=val,data_type='n') # Cell.TYPE_NUMERIC
   wb.save(plotDir + '\\' + plotFile[:-4] + '.xlsx')
```

Comment: Nico238, thanks for the help. But now when trying to open that file using "read_excel", It is showing an error "ValueError: could not convert string to float". Can you pls help further to debug this issue?

Comment: It means that you have a cell that cannot be converted to a float, my example assumes that all your data were numerics. Could you please send a sample of your csv?

Comment: You can download the CSV from here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y0P4t0IenOoiH1mMGzJqm6M32lhOQ77y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I did some changes according to column number.
And now it is working perfectly.
Thanks for the solution :)